# How do I double every other element in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to output two arrays at the end of the program.

The first array is what the user inputs. The second array should copy the elements of the first and replace every other element by its double. Say the user saves "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" to the first array. The second array should have: "1, **4**, 3, **8**, 5".

Here is what I have so far.

Head Tags

```
function toDouble(modArray)
{
   var modified = new Array();
   for(var i = 1; i < modArray.length; i+=2)
   {
      modified.push(modArray[i] * 2); 
   }
return modified;
}
```

---

Body Tags

```
var origArray = new Array();
var modArray = new Array();
while() //ignore the while loop part; it is working fine
{ 
   origArray = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: ")); 
   document.write(origArray); //output 1
   modArray.push(origArray);
}
var modified = toDouble(modArray); 
document.write(modified); //output 2
```

I'm receiving only the doubled numbers and not the entire array. For example, if I enter "1, 2, 3, 4, 5", I get only "4, 8" as output.

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you expect "1, 4, 3, 8, 5" of "2, 4, 6, 8, 10"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:-

```
function toDouble(modArray) {
    for (var i = 1; i < modArray.length; i+=2) {
        modArray[i] *= 2;
    }
    return modArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to make a few changes to your code:

```js
function toDouble(modArray) {
   var modified = modArray.slice(0); // copy the whole `modArray`
   for(var i = 1; i < modified.length; i+=2) {
      modified[i] *= 2; // replace the value at `i`, for every other number.
   }
   return modified;
}

var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    b = toDouble(a);

alert(JSON.stringify(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toDouble(modArray)
{
    var modified = new Array();
    for(var i = 1; i < modArray.length; i+=2)
    {
        modified.push(modArray[i-1]);
        modified.push(modArray[i] * 2); 
    }

    if(modified.length < modArray.length)
        modified.push(modArray[modArray.length - 1]);
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: Try this for: `[1,2,3]`. the result will be `[1, 4]`

Comment: before return check if arrays are the same length if not push the last element...

Answer (score 0):

```
function toDouble(modArray) {
    var modified = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < modArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            modified.push(modArray[i]);
        else
            modified.push(modArray[i] * 2);
    }
    return modified;
}
```

Example:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

toDouble(a); // output: [1, 4, 3, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

As already explained the problem is when you are creating the new array you are considering only alternate elements in the original array

Another solution using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function toDouble(modArray) {
  return modArray.map(function(val, i) {
    return i % 2 == 0 ? val : val * 2;
  })
}


var modArray = new Array(),
  origArray;
while (modArray.length < 5) //ignore the while loop part; it is working fine
{
  origArray = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number: "));
  modArray.push(origArray);
}

snippet.log('modArray: ' + modArray)
var modified = toDouble(modArray);
snippet.log('Result: ' + modified)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: When the code you add to get data _into_ the code snippet, and to get a result _from_ the code snippet, is longer than the code snippet itself, I think you should re-evaluate your priorities...

Comment: @Cerbrus sorry... didn't get you

Comment: What I mean is: The code that actually answers the question is 5 lines long. Then you add _13_ lines of irrelevant code to handle in / output. Imo, that's a little excessive.

Comment: @Cerbrus yes... in the fiddle I used to test it initially... I used a static array...

Answer (score 0):

You can also map through the array for the same outcome. Here you use the index to see if the element is in every 2nd position.

```
function toDouble(modArray) {
   return modArray.map((e,i) => i % 2 == 0 ? e : 2 * e); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**using with map upon the array **

```
const double =function(a){
const copy=[...a];//bad practice to mutate directly function parameter
const final=copy.map((cur,i)=> i%2===0?cur:2*cur;//[0/2=0]=cur,,[1/2!=0]=2*curr
return final;
}`
//output [1,4,3,8,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely late, but here is a solution using modern ES6.

```js
a.map((v, i) => {
    return i % 2 !== 0 ? v * 2 : v
})
```

With "a" being your target array.

The map function applies a function to every value in an array and creates a new array with the return values.

i % 2 !== 0 is used to tell if the index is not divisble by two, so index 0 would be no, index 1 would be yes.

Swapping out i % 2 !== 0 with i % 2 === 0 would do the same, except it would be the 0 is yes, 1 is no, etc.
The ? v * 2 : v is fancy syntax for if else. The syntax is condition ? iftrue() : iffalse().

For example,
let cond = true. Lets say, we have a new variable, res, and if cond == true, res = 1 but if cond == false, res = 2

The syntax would be `let res = cond ? 1 : 2`.

So, in short, if the index is not divisble by two, return the value doubled, else, return the value.